# Prefetching or Selecting a single model from a ManyToMany field for use in a Serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

We have a model with a ManyToMany through table like such

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        Person,
        through="Membership",
        through_fields=("group", "person"),
    )

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

On our `Group` view we would like to create a single-model access to the `Membership` model based on `request.user` so that our serializer can access fields of the pivot table like

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializer.CharField(source='memberships.user.name')
```

I have tried a query such as

```
Group.objects.filter(user=request.user).annotate(
  request_user_membership=Subquery(Membership.objects.filter(group_id=OuterRef('id'), user_id=request.user.id))
)
```

so that I might be able to reference the single object like

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_name = serializer.CharField(source='request_user_membership.user.name')
```

however it does not seem that you can use subqueries like this.

This seems like a common problem so I was hoping you all might have some ideas.

Any help is greatly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The design for the models could be like the following:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Membership(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="members")
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="groups")
```

In the serializer, you can get all the members in the group, or just select the one of them.

```
class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    // to get all the members
    members = PersonSerializer(many = True, read_only = True)

    // your customized field
    user_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only = True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'members', 'user_name', )
        model = Group

    def get_user_name(self, obj):
        if obj.members.count() == 0:
            return ""
        else:
            return obj.members[0].name
```